# Cannot call method of on of undefined

Tags: javascript, button, extjs, playframework

I was wondering if someone could tell me why the below code is not working. The first 2 on functions are working and then the last on function is not working and I am getting the error message "cannot call method of on of undefined."

It seems to not like this line, textF.getEl().on('click', function() {

```
    bUpdateSwitch.on({'click': function (){
        var textF = Ext.getCmp('rateSummary');
        textF.enable();
        textF.getEl().on('click', function() {
            Ext.getCmp('rtCurrency').enable();
            Ext.getCmp('rtCurrency').setReadOnly(false); 
            Ext.getCmp('rtAccEffDate').enable(); 
            Ext.getCmp('rtAccEffDate').setReadOnly(false); 
            Ext.getCmp('rtAccExDate').enable(); 
            Ext.getCmp('rtAccExDate').setReadOnly(false); 
            Ext.getCmp('rtJctR260').enable(); 
            Ext.getCmp('rtJctR260').setReadOnly(false); 
            Ext.getCmp('switchRate').enable(); 
            Ext.getCmp('switchRate').setReadOnly(false);       
        });
    }})
```

Comment: probably one of the queried components doesn't exist, check the line number causing the error in your console

Comment: The error message tells you what is happening. The method of `getEl()` is returning undefined. :)

Comment: Use the debugger in Chrome to see what's going on.

Comment: All of the queried components should be defined. I checked the chrome debugger and it says that the .getEl().on is causing the issue, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: You can check if you defined an id "rateSummary" in your pseudo object  definition.

Comment: I just checked and it looks like rateSummary is an id and not a name

Comment: I don't see why this questions is tagged under "playframework" as it's only about Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

That means that your `rateSummary` component is not rendered at the time this function is executed. Hence `getEl()` returns `undefined` and calling a method on `undefined` crashes with the error message you've reported...

What is this component exactly? Can you not register the listener on the component directly, instead of its element? Like this:

```
textF.on('click', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Otherwise, do it like this, and Ext will take care of waiting for the rendering:

```
textF.on({
    el: {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I just made it textF.on('click', function() {